# JSON tabular format parsing in c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, deserialization

I'm trying to work with CPI data from the Bureau of Labor and Statistics and I am having trouble deserializing the JSON data below:

{
    "status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
    "responseTime": 66,
    "message": [],
    "Results": {
        "series": [
            {
                "seriesID": "CUUR0000SA0",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "237.838",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "237.945",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "238.316",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "238.654",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "238.638",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "237.805",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "236.599",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "236.119",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "234.722",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "233.707",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M13",
                        "periodName": "Annual",
                        "value": "236.736",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "234.812",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "236.151",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "237.433",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "238.031",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "237.852",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "238.250",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "238.343",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "237.900",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "237.072",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "236.293",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "234.781",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "233.916",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M13",
                        "periodName": "Annual",
                        "value": "232.957",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "233.049",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "233.069",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "233.546",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "234.149",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "233.877",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "233.596",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "233.504",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "232.945",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "232.531",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "232.773",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "232.166",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "230.280",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

My c# is below...  what is interesting is that if I use the RootObject class I actually return the status and response time but if I use the Datum class I get nothing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{

public class Footnote
{
}

public class Datum
{
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string period { get; set; }
    public string periodName { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public List<Footnote> footnotes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Year: {0}", year);
    }
}

public class Series
{
    public string seriesID { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Series: {0} \n Data: {1}", seriesID, data);
    }
}

public class Results
{
    public List<Series> series { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int responseTime { get; set; }
    public List<object> message { get; set; }
    public Results Results { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Status: {0} \n Response Time: {1}", status, responseTime);
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TryParse();
    }


    static void getJson()
    {

    }

    static void TryParse()
    {
        //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CUUR0000SA0");
        //WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        //string jsonString = response.ToString();

         string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\json.txt");


        ////This returns nothing
        Datum p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(jsonString);


        ////This works and returns the data
        //RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);



        Console.WriteLine(p1);
        Console.ReadLine();


        }

    }
}
```

I would like to be able to list out the year, periodName, and values for all of the Datum.  Could anyone help me extract this data from this JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must start with RootObject because that is how the json is formatted. Then you can navigate to the Datum Array.

```
RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(p1.Results.series[0].data[0].year);
```

To List all values, you can loop:

```
foreach(Datum d in p1.Results.series[0].data)
{
      Console.WriteLine(d.year + " : " + d.period + " : " + d.periodName + " : " + d.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a full json like the one you posted, you can't deserialize from it straight your datum, you need to parse the whole structure, so this is why

```
RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

works and returns data

at this point you have just to navigate the RootObject to find the data you need

and Datum isn't a single data but it's nested into the object hierarcy so you need to get it from the right place

Your RootObject has a list of Series (series property), and each Series has a list of Datum (data property), so you have to do an aggregate function or get a specific series and then inspect it's Datum list

giving your json, this should be enough (untested)

```
RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
var datas = p1.Result.series[0].data;
```

**update:**
I've created a fiddle for you that show you the full process to read your datum:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxel3K

e.g. to dump in console your datum this is what you need

```
RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);

    foreach(var data in p1.Results.series[0].data){
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("year: {0}; period: {1}; periodName: {2}", data.year,data.period,data.periodName));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your information is there you just need to go dig a little bit. In your root object class you could access your Datum Information like so,

```
RootObject p1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
// Keep in mind this will only iterate over first Series, if you have multiple
// series you would need to do a nested loop over that collection.
foreach(Datum item in p1.Results.series.First().data)
{
     //display Item info.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Javascript Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var parser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = parser.Deserialize<dynamic>(missionGeoData);

foreach (var temp in data){       
     yourList.Add(temp["fieldName"].ToString());
}
```